# jQuery AJAX doesn't hit WebMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post, webmethod

You might wonder it as a duplicate post.  But, I have researched a lot on various blog but I could not understand what the mistake I 'm doing.

I'm calling a web method as below

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx/Save",
    data: "{ 'Id': 'test', 'newvalue': 'test' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(err.Message);
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }
});
```

I get the alert "Success" but I never see it hitting WebMethod.  My web method is as below

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void Save(string Id, string newvalue)
    {
        //my code

    }
```

I kept breakpoint but it never hits.  I also tried with $Post but same issue

```
 $.post("test.aspx/Save", { Id: "test", newvalue: "test" }, function (data, status) {
    alert('second');
});
```

None of these calls do hit web method but I get Alert of Success in Ajax call and Alert of "second" in the post call.  Please advise, if anyone of you have any clue.   Thanks

Comment: Try sending valid json `data: '{ "Id": "test", "newvalue": "test" }',`

Comment: I tried that too. It always gives me "success" alert but never goes into web method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got a solution to this.  In my RouteConfig.cs, RedirectMode is not set correctly.  After changing mode to off, everything worked.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for an ASP.NET page, you can create a simple javascript function and call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dostuff() {

PageMethods.Save("new Id", "new Value"); //this gets any webmethod registered on your page(in this case, the "Save" you created)

}
</script>
```

ON MVC: for some reason, it seems you can't call static functions declared on your controller page with ajax, but once i removed the static keyword, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET without MVC.  I already tried this as well in my page but doesn't work.

Comment: try to declare this control on the page: `<asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="True" /> `